# TBB parallel_for compile error

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, tbb

I want to use TBB parallel_for I had this to my code for testing

```
#include <tbb/parallel_for.h>
#include <tbb/blocked_range.h>
#include <tbb/tbb.h>

std::vector<std::tuple<std::string, unsigned int, std::string>> commands;
auto n = commands.size();
tbb::parallel_for(0, n, [&](int i) {
    const auto &tuple = commands[i];
} );
```

my compile line is:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -g -Og TextMiningApp.cpp -ltbb -o TextMiningApp
```

And my compiler error is:

```
TextMiningApp.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
TextMiningApp.cpp:184:7: error: no matching function for call to ‘parallel_for(int, long unsigned int&, main(int, char**)::<lambda(int)>)’
     } );
       ^
In file included from TextMiningApp.cpp:15:0:
/usr/include/tbb/parallel_for.h:185:6: note: candidate: template<class Range, class Body> void tbb::parallel_for(const Range&, const Body&)
 void parallel_for( const Range& 
      ^
```

Do you have an idea to solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem of your code is that `0` is of type `int`, while `n` is of type `std::size_t`. There's a mismatch, and you need a conversion. The solution is as follows:

```
tbb::parallel_for(static_cast<std::size_t>(0), n, [&](std::size_t i)) {
    // other code    
}
```

Another solution is to use `tbb::blocked_range<T>` to specify the range, i.e. another overload for `tbb::parallel_for`.

```
tbb::parallel_for(tbb::blocked_range<std::size_t>(0, n),
    [&](const tbb::blocked_range<std::size_t> &range) {
        for (auto i = range.begin(); i != range.end(); ++i)
            const auto &tuple = commands[i];
    } );
```

Obviously, the first solution is more concise. However, the second one is more flexible. Because for the first one, you can only specify the loop body, while for the second one, you can do more outside the loop body.

Comment: thanks commands is not empty i just remove the code. in the lamda there is still a for? so parallel for just give you a smaller range?

Comment: for my code i go to https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/tutorial-intel-tbb-generic-parallel-algorithms, this tutorial have invalid code?

Comment: The tutorial is valid. I usually use the `tbb::blocked_range` interface, and ignored the other one. I've updated the answer. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: thank you again @for_stack, What is the better (or more performant) solution?

Comment: The 'index' overload eventually calls the 'blocked_range' overload to do the real work. They should have the same performance. Obviously, the 'index'  overload is more concise. However, the 'blocked_range' overload is more flexible. The lambda for the 'index' overload is just the loop body, while the lambda for the 'overload' version can do more outside the loop body.